# Using Interop Excel to export gridview to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, interop

Planning on using interop on my project because the previous methods give me a popup warning every time the file is opened in excel saying that the version is different from the file format.

Question is, which Object Library version do I have to add to my project's References? According to the ms site:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186(v=vs.80).aspx
```

`Depending on the version of Office installed the Excel Assembly may be called Excel 10 Object Library or Excel 11 Object Library.`

Does this mean that interop can only be used with one version of Excel? If I use this certain version of Object Library, then I can only use it in par with Excel 2003. Is that what this mean?

Comment: "because the previous methods give me a popup warning every time the file is opened in excel saying that the version is different from the file format" that's because your excel files have wrong extension '.xlsx' instead of '.xls' or vice versa.

Comment: @petr no, I'm saving it as .xls but the warning still goes.

Comment: I think you get the warning because the file is not really in excel format (could be csv or html)... I used to do it in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The statement you quoted only means that the assembly you would reference depends on which version of excel you have installed on the box running your program.

So if you have Excel 2007 in your box, then you should reference the Excel12 library. However, it does not follow that the clients should have the same version. In Excel 2007, you may save the files in xml format (xlsx) and it would be readable to clients with excel 2007+ and older versions with a certain [Compatibility Pack](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/open-an-office-excel-2007-workbook-in-an-earlier-version-of-excel-HA010014107.aspx). Using the same library, you can also save your files in the older xls format for compatibility, which I think can be opened up til Excel 97 (some features may be disabled).

Comment: what if the web app is gonna be deployed in a web server / intranet network? does it have to have excel on it as well? or interop looks for excel in the client's (one who's viewing the site) laptop?

Comment: actually no, it doesn't work that way. you have to have excel installed on your server. use the excel interop to create an excel file and then you send the file over the wire to your clients.

Comment: I suggest you generate and save your excel file somewhere in your server (or db) instead of regenerating the excel file for every user.. or alternatively, if you use it for repoting, use something like SSIS or reporting services... and let them generate the excel file for you.